# Xamarin - Could not load assembly 'PCLStorage.Abstractions

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, nuget, xamarin.forms

After adding the FlurlHttp Nuget package to my PCL project my app will no longer deploy to my emulator due to an assembly loading error

> Error      Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'PCLStorage.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=286fe515a2c35b64'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
>   File name: 'PCLStorage.Abstractions.dll'
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at 
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() InfoSupport.AV.MobileClient.Droid   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1347

The build system is also reporting conflicts :

> There was a conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes". (TaskId:77)
>   2>      "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" was chosen because it was primary and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes" was not. (TaskId:77)
>
> There was a conflict between "PCLStorage.Abstractions, Version=0.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=286fe515a2c35b64" and "PCLStorage.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=286fe515a2c35b64". (TaskId:142)
>   2>      "PCLStorage.Abstractions, Version=0.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=286fe515a2c35b64" was chosen because it was primary and "PCLStorage.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=286fe515a2c35b64" was not. (TaskId:142)

These errors appeared after adding the `Microsoft.Build.Async (1.0.168)`, `Microsoft.Bcl.Build(1.0.21)`, `Microsoft.Net.Http(2.2.29)`, `Microsoft.Bcl (1.1.10)` nuget packages to my 
PCL project, Xamarin forms project and Xamarin Droid project.

In addition, the Nuget packages `Xamarin.Forms.Maps (v2.1.0.6508)` and `Xamarin.Forms (v2.1.0.6508-pre3)` are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the nuget package PclStorage v1.0.2 to the PCL project resolves both warnings and the deployment error.

I'm not sure why this dependency is there.

Comment: You should always add NuGets to ALL projects. PCL storage for instance has platform specific implementations, which is most likely why it threw an error.

Comment: The issue would have been more straightforward had the package been added to other projects. As it stands, the package is only added to the PCL project.